# android.widget.AbsListView$RecycleBin.getScrapView NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array

Tags: java, android, listview, arraylist, nullpointerexception

I have an Android app using a ListView and adapter. I am also using this library: https://github.com/baoyongzhang/SwipeMenuListView.

I see in my crash reporting that this is happening to certain users, but when I examine the stacktrace I can't figure out what's causing it - there's no mention of any Activity, Fragment or Class. I also checked the source code for `AbsListView` ([here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/widget/AbsListView.java)) and have no idea what I'm looking for. I only have one activity in my app that imports `AbsListView` but it's not being called.

My initial suspicion was that I was doing `setAdapter()` in some instances where my ArrayList is null, but I checked and I do a null check before this. Has anyone seen this before? Is it actually crashing the app?

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
at android.widget.AbsListView$RecycleBin.getScrapView(AbsListView.java:6803)
at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2364)
at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1408)
at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1315)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22071)
at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.internalMeasureChildren(ConstraintLayout.java:1227)
at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.onMeasure(ConstraintLayout.java:1572)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22071)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6602)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22071)
at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.onMeasure(ConstraintLayout.java:1676)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22071)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6602)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
at androidx.appcompat.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:146)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22071)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6602)
at androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:490)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22071)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6602)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22071)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6602)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1514)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:806)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:685)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22071)
at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6602)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:724)
at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22071)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2422)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1504)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1761)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1392)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6752)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:911)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:723)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:658)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:897)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

Comment: did you solve this problem?

Comment: @MahdiM unfortunately no.

Comment: @MahdiM I went back and checked and I'm not 100% sure, but I wrapped my setAdapter() call in a try / catch and the errors seemed to stop after that.